# Ruby on Rails - Populate modal with data from database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Pretty stumped at the moment trying to figure something out. I have a modal that shows a table, and for each of the entries in the table, I have actions (i.e., show, edit, delete, etc). When the user clicks on "Edit" for an entry row in this model, I want it to populate another model with a form to show the data associated with that entry.

Is there a convenient way to do this? For one, I do not know how to pass a parameter to a modal from another modal. I don't know how to make this form "reinitialize" after it's already been rendered when the first page is loaded.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been in the same situation and I suggest that you just keep the one modal and replace the contents through AJAX (IMO). Once you have rendered into the modal in the first place, your links can then just render as AJAX the same way that they would and overwrite the information inside the modal. The way I did it was this:

1. Populate the modal (you've already done that).
2. Create a link `= link_to "Text", "url", remote: true` (let's say this is the edit action).
3. Run the edit action in the controller as usual.
4. The `edit.js.erb` file would contain one line: `$('#Modal_content').html("<%= j render 'edit' %>")` (#Modal_content is just a div that I put in my modal so that I can replace all the contents without messing up the close button and other modal required html).
5. The `_edit.html.erb` file is called where you would put all of what you needed that comes from the edit action.

As for passing information, the id is passed through the link that you click on to call the controller#edit action.

Let me know if you need more details, but that should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Hmm, I think I follow what you're saying. So in my case where I have the modal that shows all of the table rows, let that modal be replaceable with the form as well as opposed to opening another modal? Would you happen to know of a demo using this? Seems pretty interesting but I'm getting a bit twisted in a few areas.

Comment: Exactly. Just replace all of the content with your new form, then replace the form on submission with the original content like you did before. You could do multiple modals like you originally thought, but according to the [Bootstrap modal documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), multiple modals are not supported.

Comment: Oh ok. Makes sense. At the moment it works fine without any custom code -- not quite sure why that mentions custom code is necessary. However, I think I prefer your suggestion instead. Thanks! I'm going to look more into going up this route.

Comment: Again, just let me know if you have any questions about specific details and I can give you more detailed answers.

Comment: Will do! Much appreciated! :)

Comment: Almost there. I just added <script type="text/javascript">$('#modal_content').html("test")</script>; just for giggles at the bottom of my modal view, but when i reload the page, nothing gets replaced. I have also added <div class="modal_content"> right underneath the <div class="modal-body">, but nothing gets changed when the page loads. Could you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: You are searching for the ID modal content in the jquery call, but you have the div as a class. Make the div id="modal_content".

Comment: Thank you!! :) I may have one final question for you about the edit.js.erb stuff, but I'll research prior to wasting your time. Many thanks!

Comment: This [tutorial](http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/the-detailed-guide-on-how-ajax-works-with-ruby-on-rails) helped me out a lot when I was trying to figure things out. It has all the information I was talking about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63964/discussion-between-nikkon226-and-user3447014).